# Rust optimizing out loops?

Tags: optimization, gcc, rust

I was doing some very simple benchmarks to compare performance of C and Rust. I used a function adding integers `1 + 2 + ... + n` (something that I could verify by a computation by hand), where `n = 10^10`.

The code in Rust looks like this:

```
fn main() {
  let limit: u64 = 10000000000;
  let mut buf: u64 = 0;
  for u64::range(1, limit) |i| {
    buf = buf + i;
  }
  io::println(buf.to_str());
}
```

The C code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned long long buf = 0;
  for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < 10000000000; ++i) {
    buf = buf + i;
  }
  printf("%llu\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and run them:

```
$ rustc sum.rs -o sum_rust
$ time ./sum_rust
13106511847580896768

real        6m43.122s
user        6m42.597s
sys 0m0.076s
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 sum.c -o sum_c
$ time ./sum_c
13106511847580896768

real        1m3.296s
user        1m3.172s
sys         0m0.024s
```

Then I tried with optimizations flags on, again both C and Rust:

```
$ rustc sum.rs -o sum_rust -O
$ time ./sum_rust
13106511847580896768

real        0m0.018s
user        0m0.004s
sys         0m0.012s
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 sum.c -o sum_c -O9
$ time ./sum_c
13106511847580896768

real        0m16.779s
user        0m16.725s
sys         0m0.008s
```

These results surprised me. I *did* expected the optimizations to have some effect, but the optimized Rust version is *100000 times* faster :).

I tried changing `n` (the only limitation was `u64`, the run time was still virtually zero), and even tried a different problem (`1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + ... + n^5`), with similar results: executables compiled with `rustc -O` are several orders of magnitude faster than without the flag, and are also many times faster than the same algorithm compiled with `gcc -O9`.

So my question is: what's going on? :) I could understand a compiler optimizing `1 + 2 + .. + n = (n*n + n)/2`, but I can't imagine that any compiler could derive a formula for `1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + .. + n^5`. On the other hand, as far as I can see, *the result must've been computed somehow* (and it seems to be correct).

Oh, and:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.6 (dba9337 2013-05-10 05:52:48 -0700)
host: i686-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Just a data point, clang makes it `movabsq $-5340232226128654848, %rsi` here for the simple sum, and `movabsq $1667352834054815744, %rsi` for `i*i*i*i*i`, so rust eliminating the loop is not so special (I'm kind of surprised gcc doesn't).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, compilers do use the `1 + ... + n = n*(n+1)/2` optimisation to remove the loop, and there are similar tricks for any power of the summation variable. e.g. [*k<sup>1</sup>* are triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), [*k<sup>2</sup>* are pyramidal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), [*k<sup>3</sup>* are squared triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number), etc. In general, there is even a formula to calculate [∑<sub>*k*</sub> *k<sup>p</sup>* for any *p*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

---

You can use a more complicated expression, so that the compiler doesn't have any tricks to remove the loop. e.g.

```
fn main() {
  let limit: u64 = 1000000000;
  let mut buf: u64 = 0;
  for u64::range(1, limit) |i| {
    buf += i + i ^ (i*i);
  }
  io::println(buf.to_str());
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned long long buf = 0;
  for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    buf += i + i ^ (i * i);
  }
  printf("%llu\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

which gives me

```
real    0m0.700s
user    0m0.692s
sys     0m0.004s
```

and

```
real    0m0.698s
user    0m0.692s
sys     0m0.000s
```

respectively (with `-O` for both compilers).

Comment: Thank you, I underestimated the compiler :). But why does LLVM contain such a special optimization?